SUMIFS + ARRAYFORMULA with multiple criterias
I am trying to create an automatic dividend tracker that will add values from my transaction list (dividends received) in Google Sheets, but I can't seem to get the formula to work completely. I have created a formula that has allowed me to add the dividends received from the transactions list for specific months but I cannot figure out how to modify the formula to only add up the transactions for a specific year (2023, and 2024 separate + future years) and specific month
Here is the formula I have so far:
​=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA( FIND("Jan", 'Fidelity Brokerage Transactions'!G$4:G)), 1, 'Fidelity Brokerage Transactions'!$J$4:J)​

I am going to provide pictures and a link to the Google sheet to make it easier to visualize. Please don't hesitate to reach out with questions.
Link to Google sheets


I have posted the same question on the google support forum so please check to link below to see if an answer has already been provided.
Link to the same question on Google support forums

Hello there! I have noticed that there is already an answer posted on the Google Support forum. Kindly check if the answer provided on the forum works.

I have received the answer to my problem from the Google support forum and I would like to share the solution that I was provided by Prashanth KV
"
Please clear everything in cells B4:I15.
Then enter this formula into cell B4. Do not copy and paste it into other cells.
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(EOMONTH('Fidelity Brokerage Transactions'!G4:G, -1)+1, DATE(B3:I3, MONTH(A4:A15& 1), 1), 'Fidelity Brokerage Transactions'!J4:J))
"
